# Spring Security OAuth2 Flow - What Does Spring Boot Do After Redirect?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am trying to use OAuth2 to authenticate / authorize users in a Spring Boot MVC application.

From the [Spring Security docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/core.html#:%7E:text=The%20default%20redirect%20URI%20template,the%20application%20is%20correctly%20configured.), I know that the default redirect uri (where the authentication server redirects to with an authorization code after successful sign in) is `{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}`.

However, what happens at this point? Does Spring Boot provide this endpoint and handle things? Or do I need to make a controller that maps this endpoint (e.g. `@GetMapping(/login/oauth2/code/{registrationId}, ...)`, and deal with things myself?

If Spring does things for me, what exactly does it do? I notice that you can specify a `security.oauth2.client.provider.<registrationId>.token-uri` in the `application.yml` file. Does this mean Spring Boot will automatically fetch the access token for you when the redirect uri is accessed?

Basically, I am wondering how I can get the access token from the server after the user has successfully logged in. If Spring Boot gets the access token for you, how can I get it from Spring Boot to use it in HTTP requests?

Comment: why do you need the token?

Comment: The structure of the application I am working with requires it to be passed between various components. This isn't something I have the liberty to change.

Comment: Please have a look at the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/client/authorized-clients.html